# How to load data "on-demand" in Redux/React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to make a simple React+Redux app that gets data from the server. I understand basic principles of the Redux, but I cannot find anywhere in tutorials an example of how to implement something like "loading data on-demand".
My API can return list of the books, like this:

```
 [
  {
    title: 'The Hobbit',
    authorId: 1
  },
  {
    title: 'The Colour of Magic',
    authorId: 2
  }
]
```

And there is another call to get data by specific author, this call will return something like this (by authorId):

```
{
  title: 'J. R. R. Tolkien',
  authorId: 1
}

 or

{
  title: 'Terry Pratchett',
  authorId: 2
}
```

I have these methods in my "actions" file:

```
export function loadBooksSuccessfully(books) {
    return {type: types.LOAD_BOOKS, books};
}

export function loadBooks() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return MyApi.getBooks().then(data => {
            dispatch(loadBooksSuccessfully(data));
        }).catch(err => {
            throw(err);
        });
    };
}
```

I call loadBooks() action in the main js file to display the list of the books when the page was loaded. My problem is that I don't know where should I request info about authors to display list in the following format:

Book: "The Hobbit"
Author: "J. R. R. Tolkien"

Book: "The Colour of Magic"
Author: "Terry Pratchett"

I have react components 'BooksList' and 'BookItem' for rendering the layout.
I pass the list of the books to the BooksList via mapStateToProps method:

```
class BooksList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let books = this.props.books;

        return <div>
            {books.map((book) => {
                return <BookItem key={`my-book-${book.id}`}
                                 {...book} />
            })}
        </div>
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        books: state.app.books
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BooksList);
```

Here is my BookItem react component:

```
class BookItem extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        const book = this.props.book;

        return (<div>
            <div>
                Book: {book.name}
            </div>
            <div>
                Author: {book.author.name}
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

Here is actions for loading author info:

```
export function loadAuthorSuccessfully(author) {
    return {type: types.LOAD_AUTHOR, author};
}

export function loadAuthor(authorId) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return MyApi.getAuthor(authorId).then(data => {
            console.info('DATA', data);
            dispatch(loadAuthorSuccessfully(data));
        }).catch(err => {
            throw(err);
        });
    };
}
```

I was thinking to call loadAuthor() method in the componentDidMount method of the BookItem component but it doesn't seem like real redux solution. What is the canonical way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Loading data with Redux is simply a specific case of dispatching an action.

To dispatch an action from React, you have generally two options:

1) You dispatch in some event handler - the user clicking a button or link, toggling a checkbox... a response to an event.
2) You dispatch when a specific Componente is about to mount / mounted - something appears on screen without the user needing to click around.

The first case is very simple, map your action creators using `connect` and call that new injected prop in your handler.

For the second, you still need to bind your action creator, and then you use one of React lifecycle events like this

```
class AuthorPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.loadAuthor()
  }
}
```

This second approach means you need to take into account that the data may not be ready when the component is first rendered, so you will likely keep that in your Redux state and display a spinner or null until it is.

Hope it helps, I suggest you watch Dan Abramov's Egghead video series. 2h of your time will save you dozens at Stackoverflow. :)